# Partitioning/RAID approach for a fresh RHEL installation

Tags: raid, redhat, operating-system, rhel8

I just inherited a brand new HPE DL360 Server with 6x600GB and 2x300GB HDD drives in it and 16GB of RAM and i'm planning to install a fresh RHEL distribution. Having not much experience with RAIDS and partitioning, i would like to ask what would be the best RAID approach for these drives and also, what would be the recommended size of the partitions that i'm going to manually create during the installation. Here are the partitions:

- Swap
- /boot
- root partition "/"
- /home partition to store user data

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

R1 mirror of the 2 x 300GB as your OS/boot/root drive then a R10 or R6 of the 6 x 600GB for data, which you choose depends on whether you need the 1.1TB of slower space of R6 or the 850GB of faster R10. Oh and get more memory, it's cheap.

Out of interest which specific DL360 have you got? the Gen10 or 10+ and which version of RHEL are you using?

Comment: That's what i had in mind after doing some research. Although R10 has excellent read and write speeds, i'll stil be losing half of the total storage space. I think i might have to go with R5 or R6 for the 6x600GB drives. Any idea on the recommended partitions size  ?  And to answer your question, it's a DL360 Gen10 with a RHEL 8 if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Please don't use R5, no storage pro would think of using it, we consider it almost irresponsible that controller manufacturers still allow it!. If I were you I've use LVM throughout and just have a single LVM partition, make life easier when you want to add more disks in the future.